# Headquarter Relocation and Stock Return - Influence of Universities

Tags: finance, reference-request, corporate-actions

Scott Galloway states in chapter 8, *The T Algorithm*, in his book [The Four: The Hidden DNA of Amazon, Apple, Facebook, and Google](http://www.thefourbook.com), that a successful strategy to become a "trillion dollar company" must consider geography:

> A companies headquarter should be located near a world-class technical or engineering teaching university.

**Is there any academic paper which specifically analyzes that a headquarter relocation towards a high-ranking university generates higher stock returns in subsequent periods?**

Scott Galloway gives no reference for this statement, but mentions Nike Inc. as an example, that they *should* clearly profit (he estimates up to 10 billion US-$) from a relocation. I just found general studies from [Chinmoy et al. (1995)](https://doi.org/10.1006/juec.1995.1034) on stock price effects of headquarters relocations. Further papers like [Pirinsky/Wang (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2006.00895.x) and the related (and also current) literature focuses solely on the return co-movement of stocks where the companies headquarters are nearly located.

Comment: I would be interested to see any papers on this, it could be a really interesting MSc/PhD research paper